# How do I edit Node Values in an Xml File with C#

Tags: c#, xml, innertext

I am trying to change the values in a Farming simulator 22 savegame xml file from C# in visual studio. There are a lot of nodes so I have reduced them to make things easier. I want to know how to replace the value in the node using C# with out having to create and rebuild the xml file from scratch.

the path to the xml file is: (C:\Users\Name\Documents\My Games\FarmingSimulator2022\savegame1\careerSavegame.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<careerSavegame revision="2" valid="true">
  <settings>
    <savegameName>My game save</savegameName>
    <creationDate>2022-05-03</creationDate>
    <mapId>MapFR</mapId>
    <mapTitle>Haut-Beyleron</mapTitle>
    <saveDateFormatted>2022-08-22</saveDateFormatted>
    <saveDate>2022-08-22</saveDate>
    <resetVehicles>false</resetVehicles>
</careerSavegame>
```

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.setvalue?view=net-6.0

Comment: XSLT is the best technology for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some research I found the solution to editing the values within the nodes. In this example I only change the value of savegameName, but it will be the same for the rest.

```
    //Routing the xml file 
    XmlDocument xmlsettings = new XmlDocument();
    xmlsettings.Load(@"D:\careerSavegame.xml");

    //Setting values to nodes through innertext
    String FarmNameSetting = "Martek Farm";
    XmlNode savegameNamenode = 
    xmlsettings.SelectSingleNode
    ("careerSavegame/settings/savegameName");
    savegameNamenode.InnerText = FarmNameSetting;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`System.Xml.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=net-6.0) namespace to access the `xml` file. This will load the file in the memory.

There is one class inside it, [`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-6.0), that represents the `xml` document.

```cs
String filePath = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\My Games\FarmingSimulator2022\savegame1\careerSavegame.xml"
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var element = xdoc.Elements("MyXmlElement").Single();
element.Value = "foo";
xdoc.Save("file.xml");
```

You can set the `element` variable as per the one which is needed to be replaced.